# Illegal mix of collations mysql error?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I am using `geoloaction` to find the current location of user which returns the xml data

```
<geonames>
    <geoname>
        <toponymName>Gulbahar</toponymName>
        <name>Golīmar</name>
        <lat>24.8922</lat>
        <lng>67.0287</lng>
        <geonameId>1346867</geonameId>
        <countryCode>PK</countryCode>
        <countryName>Pakistan</countryName>
        <fcl>P</fcl>
        <fcode>PPLX</fcode>
        <distance>0.14608</distance>
    </geoname>
</geonames>
```

now i want `<name>Golīmar</name>`  which has a special character and on the basis of that name i have to run the query to fetch more results except this one but it generates some sort of collation  errors

```
SELECT DISTINCT country
FROM   propertydetails
WHERE  country NOT IN ( "Golīmar" )
```

> Error:Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) AND
>   (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) FOR operation

i have seen many stack pos but couldnt find a way to resolve

Comment: Check the collation of your table: SHOW CREATE TABLE propertydetails; Then you will probably have to switch the collation from latin1 to utf-8, or thos of the database connection itself. Let me know what is your table encoding.

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE propertydetails; this command shows the table name no other details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my above problem by

```
SELECT DISTINCT country
FROM   propertydetails
WHERE  country NOT IN ( _latin1 "Golīmar" )
```

and the charset and collations of both connection and table to `latin1` , `latin1_swedish_ci`

Answer (score 0):

Your table collation and your connection collation don't match closely enough to make the query work. Make sure that they are both the same, preferably `utf8_general_ci`.

Comment: your connection collation?? i cant get this can you explain more about this

Comment: [MySQL documentation, §10.1.4, "Connection Character Sets and Collations"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-connection.html)

Comment: my charset is utf8 and collation is set to utf8_general_ci