# Illegal mix of collations in mysql + codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL Illegal mix of collations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247120/mysql-illegal-mix-of-collations)

I am implementing a query using codeigniter framework.

I always get this error "Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='" When implementing this query below:

```
 $customer_name = "orduña's";

 $escape_string = mysql_escape_string($customer_name);

 $sql = "SELECT* FROM raw_customer WHERE customer_name ='$escape_string'";
 $query = $this->db->query($sql);
 return $query->row_array();
```

I am very sure that my database is already set to utf8 charset and utf8_general_ci for collation and even tried utf8_unicode_ci.

I am also very sure that my database tables are also consistent to utf8 as well.

I am also very sure that utf 8 meta tags in headers are also implemented on the head tag.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this query as the reference of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190293/illegal-mix-of-collations-mysql-error) same problem but having the charset and collations of both connection and table to `latin1` , `latin1_swedish_ci`

```
$sql = "SELECT* FROM raw_customer WHERE customer_name =( _utf8 '$escape_string' )";
```